# Como atribuir a PK do usuario logado no Django para uma FK no model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Olá, o que eu estou tentando fazer é basicamente o seguinte, eu tenho na minha aplicação um Model chamado 'Compras', e um dos campos desse Model é o usuário que cadastrou a compra, eu quero que cada usuário logado na aplicação veja apenas os registros que ele mesmo fez, e como para adicionar um registro tem que estar logado, eu quero que o sistema automaticamente relacione a PrimaryKey do usuário com a ForeignKey do registro da Compra, o que eu tenho até agora é mais ou menos isso:

arquivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.conf import settings


class Compras(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    data = models.DateField()
    parcelas = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    ususario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Arquivo `views.py`:

```
from .models import Compras, Vendas
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


class CreateCompra(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Compras
    fields = ['nome', 'descricao', 'valor', 'data', 'parcelas', 'ususario']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tela_inicial')
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% block title %}PatchApp - Nova Compra{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Salvar</button>
    <a type="button" href="{% url 'tela_inicial' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Começo</a>
    <a type="button" href="{% url 'compras_lista' %}" class="btn btn-info">Lista</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Como está aparecendo:
[image: Formulário completo.]
O campo usuário mostra todos os usuarios do sistema:
[image: campo usuario]

Dessa forma aparece uma lista com todos os usuários para eu escolher um, mas como eu disse, eu quero que esse campo não apareça, e que ele seja preenchido automaticamente com o usuário que já está logado, como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tente fornecer mais subsidios para quem quiser ajudar, tentar entender o contexto, por exemplo: onde esta aparecendo "uma lista com todos os usuários"? E o código da template? Vc importa `TemplateView` e usa `CreateView` pq?

Comment: Na vdd eu tenho varias views nesse app, e na hora de copiar o código ficou faltando uns imports, eu coloquei agora tbm o template, q basicamente é só o form que vem pronto da view, e coloquei umas imagens de como está aparecendo.

Comment: Ok, que tal tentar se adequar [a isso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Onde vc esta definindo a template na view? Onde vc esta definindo a classe do form na view?

Comment: Pelo q eu entendi da documentação, o template o django pega automaticamente de app/classe_form.html, e tbm gera o form através do fields = ['campos'], por isso eu não coloquei, mas da proxima vez eu vou prestar mais atenção nisso, obrigado.

Comment: Sobre esse ultimo comentário, pense no zen do python: "Explicito é melhor que implicito" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora sua pergutna não esteja suficientemente clara para mim, vou tentar responder com o que eu entendi. Voce não mostra a definição do seu form, mas o que vc precisa fazer é excluir o campo `usuario`, entao seu form deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

forms.py

```
class ComprasCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Compras
        exclude = ('usuario',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usuario = kwargs.pop('usuario')
        super(ComprasCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Na view vc precisara criar uma chave em `kwargs` para o usario que deverá ser "capturado" através do request, sua view deverá ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
class CreateCompra(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Compras
    form_class = ComprasCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tela_inicial')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.usuario = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    # Aqui vc cria a chave usuario em kwargs 
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CreateCompra, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['usuario'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Com as devidas adaptações para o seu contexto, deverá funcionar.